# Android Root ICS for Panda Board

Tags: android, pandaboard

I've download the ICS source and built it for my pandaboard.
After installing ICS on the [Pandaboard](http://pandaboard.org/) I realized it was not rooted.

Can someone guide me as to how to root the ICS on pandaboard? I'm okay with having to change the kernel source but I suspect there must be an other way.

Basically I have an app that needs to execute a command that requires superuser permissions so I need superuser access on my pandaboard.

Comment: Note that being able to get an adb shell as root, and having some setuid executable kicking around for random apps to use to launch root helper processes are two quite different things.  An android emulator has the former due to not having ro.secure set, it does not have the latter, though a lot of custom ROMs do.

Comment: yeah, i  need the latter... know of any custom roms for pandaboard?

Comment: You should be able to extract/port that mechanism from any popular open build intended for phones/tablets to yours.  But it would be better to build support or an interface for your root-required task into the platform, rather than give some app the ability to cause arbitrary commands to run as root.

Comment: Interesting/Good point Chris, I'll think about it! Thanks.

Comment: @Ali can you please share the procedure or link to port Android ICS over  PandaBoard ? as i looking for the same

Comment: This is the link that was most useful. Though it seems to be down now: http://fosiao.com/node/19
Other link I have saved is: http://omappedia.org/wiki/Android_Panda_Build_Source
I haven't done this in over a year so I can't really tell from memory what you need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know how to build AOSP source tree you should be able to edit the ./system/core/rootdir/init.rc file and adjust permissions. For example, to get console root access you need to edit the "service console /system/bin/sh" section and change user and group to root.

```
service console /system/bin/sh
    class core
    console
    disabled
    user root
    group root
```

After this you can rebuild your boot image to update your ramdisk with new init.rc. Just run make bootimage, and upload newly created boot image with the fastboot to your PandaBoard SD card.

```
fastboot flash boot
```

Make sure you put your PandaBoard into fastboot mode.

Comment: That would mean if I was in shell I would be SU. I need something where I can give certain apps SU privileges like you are able to go with you root your device. I suspect we have to hack the su.c file for this, just dont know how. I realize your setups are correct but I believe the same can be achieved with `lunch full_panda-userdebug` .

Comment: Exactly, so take a look at the init.rc file. I just gave you an example, but there you will be able to change permissions for all kinds of services.